# Do I need to create Header Search Path for this structure?

Tags: ios, xcode

Do I need to create `Header Search Path` for this structure in my XCode? If yes, anyone can help me what could be the `Header Search Path`? Is it `./google-api-objectivec-client-read-only`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this `$(inherited) $(SRCROOT)/google-api-objectivec-client-read-only`.

If you need to recursively search inside the direct you can append a `**`